# Raw sql to query builder for whereBetween

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

SQL query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.employee_id ,b.name as user_name, a.start_from, a.end_to, a.leaving_reason
FROM employee_leaves as a
JOIN users as b on a.user_id = b.id
WHERE (start_from BETWEEN '2021-04-21' AND '2021-04-30')
```

This is working fine and data is coming as expected. But when I converting into laravel query builder this is not working. If any one could help me out.

Query Builder query:

```
$data=DB::table('employee_leaves as a')
                        ->join('users as b', 'a.user_id', '=', 'b.id')
                        ->whereBetween('start_from', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
                        ->select('a.*', 'b.name as user_name', 'b.id as user_id', 'b.employee_id')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Are `$request->from_date` and `$request->to_date` in `Y-m-d` format?

Comment: @Autista_z  yes the format is in `Y-m-d`

Comment: And can you be more specific, what `is not working` means? It does not filter, it returns error ... You can try use `toSql()`  insted of `get()` and dump created SQL query. And we will see the difference.

Comment: @Autista_z thank you problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed this`->whereBetween('start_from', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))`

to this `->whereBetween('start_from', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date])`

now this is working fine for me